# About the current-current correlator

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Generally, in the expression of conductivity (e.g., the Hall conductivity), we have the current-current correlator. I know it must be from the Kubo formula. The spirit of the Kubo formula is to calculate the linear response of quantity $A$ to the perturbation of $B$. The current-current correlator means both $A$ and $B $ are the current operator.

While $A$ apparently should be the current operator, why should $B$ be the current operator too? Isn't it the electric field operator?

Comment: The Kubo formula gives you linear response of $A$ due to an applied field $h(t)$ which couples to the system by a Hamiltonian $h(t) B$, in terms of a correlation function between $A$ and $B$. The conductivity is the response to an electromagnetic potential. What term do you have to add to the Hamiltonian to describe the potential's effect on the system?

Comment: @MarkMitchison  I just add $-q E x$. Here $q$ is the charge and $E$ is the electric field strength. There is no current operator here. The operator is $x$.

Comment: That's true for a single particle in the dipole approximation. Clearly, a single particle doesn't have a conductivity (although it does have a mobility). Usually one considers a many-particle system, where the relevant variables are the charge density and current.

Comment: @MarkMitchison $\Delta H = - q E x$ to represent the electric field is just a gauge choice, it's not an approximation, nor is it restricted to the single particle case.